# Add Validation to Zend form using XML

Tags: xml, zend-form

I am trying to build form using XML in Zend Framework which I have achieved.
I have also added validation to it but I am unable to display errors if the validation fails.
 Here is the xml file.

```
`

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<user>
    <login>
        <name>signup</name>
        <class>test</class>
        <method>post</method>

        <elements>
            <username>
                <type>text</type>
                <options>
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <validators>
                        <strlen>
                            enter code here<validator>StringLength</validator>
                            <options>
                                <min>4</min>
                                <max>20</max>
                            </options>
                        </strlen>
                    </validators>
                    <required>true</required>
                </options>
            </username>

            <password>
                <type>password</type>
                <options>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <validators>
                        <regex>
                            <validator>regex</validator>
                            <options>
                                <pattern>/^[a-z]/i</pattern>
                            </options>
                        </regex>
                        <strlen>
                            <validator>StringLength</validator>
                            <options>
                                <min>3</min>
                            </options>
                        </strlen>
                    </validators>
                    <required>true</required>
                </options>
            </password>

            <submit>
                <type>submit</type>
                <options>
                    <value>Submit</value>
                </options>
            </submit>
        </elements>
    </login>
</user>
```

`

The IndexController.php file

```
`

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

function indexAction() {
    $this->view->baseUrl = $this->_request->getBaseUrl();
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Zend_Form Login";

    Zend_Loader::loadClass("Zend_Config_Xml");
    $form = new Zend_Config_Xml('../application/forms/login.xml');
    $form = new Zend_Form($form->user->login);

    $form->setDecorators(array( 
                'FormElements',
                'Form' 
            )); 

    $form->setElementDecorators(array( 
        'ViewHelper', 
        'Label' 
    )); 


    foreach($form->getElements() as $element) {
        $element->addDecorators(array( 
            array('Errors', ''),
            array('HtmlTag', ''), 
            array('Label', ''), 
        )); 
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $formData = $form->getValues();
            $username = $form->getValue('username');
            $password = $form->getValue('password');

            if ($username == "admin" && $password == "root") {
                $this->_redirect("index/complete");
            } else {
                //Booh!
            }
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}

function completeAction(){}
```

}`

PLEASE HELP TO DISPLAY ERRORS IF VALIDATION FAILS
[http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.maltblue.com/php/zend-form-mastery-with-zend-config-part-3-standard-form-element-options][1]

Regards
Prashant Sudeep